# Clean way to implement gradual fading of brightness in Android?

Tags: android, brightness, fading

At the moment I have code to fade brightness adjustments which looks something like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = initial; i < target; i++) {
            final int bright = i;
            handle.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    float currentBright = bright / 100f;
                    window.getAttributes().screenBrightness = currentBright;
                    window.setAttributes(window.getAttributes());
                });
            }
            try {
                sleep(step);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

I'm not sure if that's considered good methodology (I considered using ASyncTask, but I can't see the benefits in this case). Is there a better way to achieve backlight fading?

EDIT: I'm now using a TimerTask as follows:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final float currentBright = counter[0] / 100f;
        handle.post(new Runnable() {    
            public void run() {
                window.getAttributes().screenBrightness = currentBright;
                window.setAttributes(window.getAttributes());
                if (++counter[0] <= target) {
                    cancel();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, step);
```

The reason I use an array for the counter is because it needs to be `final` to be accessed in the `Runnable`, but I need to modify the value. This uses less CPU, but still more than I like.

EDIT2: Aaaand a third attempt. Thanks to CommonsWare for the advice! (I hope I applied it correctly!)

```
    handle.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (counter[0] < target) {
                final float currentBright = counter[0] / 100f;
                window.getAttributes().screenBrightness = currentBright;            
                window.setAttributes(window.getAttributes());
                counter[0]++;
                handle.postDelayed(this, step);
            }
        }
   });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want to put device to sleep ?

Comment: No, I just want to gradually change the backlight brightness.

Comment: as far as I know there's no specific [Android Animation Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) that you can use that would fulfill your needs :-/ sorry.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try an ObjectAnimator. Thanks for the link.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you've implemented it? Looks good to me...

Comment: I don't like it because I need the CPU usage to be as low as possible. I've attempted it again using a TimerTask, I'll update the question now.

Comment: You can put a transparent layout over the whole window and animate its alpha from transparent to opaque. But it will not cover the status bar.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the question. Besides, there's better methods of creating transparent overlays than that.

Comment: FYI, if my device has Automatic brigtness checked in Display options, then window.getAttributes().screenBrightness does nothing!
This may be same on more devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about reducing the brightness to half in each iteration.

Then loop will complete in O(log n) rather than O(n) in current solution.

Comment: I like the way you think! The problem is that the brightness fade would be really jumpy initially, so it looks like it's lagging.

Comment: I tried it out, and it works quite well if the step size is small enough. Cheers!

Comment: @Glitch I am happy it worked for you && i was my first bounty here

Answer (score 1):

From Honeycomb you can do things lie this using [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html).  This [post on the Android Developers blog talks about it all in some detail](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html).

Comment: I have tried this, but I can't actually test it since I don't have a Honeycomb device. Perhaps if we had access to the source, I could implement it for other Android platforms.